# OpenCV - SURF functionality issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, opencv

I am trying to build an OpenCV program which uses SURF matching algorithm, the code is in the following link :

http://feelmare.blogspot.ro/2011/10/sift-matching-c-source-code-using.html

However, I am obtaining 2 errors regarding some external symbols : `_cvExtractSurf` and `_cvSURFParams`.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvExtractSURF referenced in function "public:    bool __thiscall CMareMatchingClass::ExtractBGsurf(struct _IplImage *)" (?ExtractBGsurf@CMareMatchingClass@@QAE_NPAU_IplImage@@@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvSURFParams referenced in function "public: __thiscall CMareMatchingClass::CMareMatchingClass(void)" (??0CMareMatchingClass@@QAE@XZ)
```

Do you know how can I solve this errors? I am running the code by using opencv 2.3.0 in visual studio 2010 in Windows 7 - 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't link a needed library - try to link all OpenCV libraries in project settings. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).